# "exoritur" in Ennius' dactylic hexameter

Tags: poetry, scansion

I'm stuck while reading Ennius' ["Cūrantēs magnā cum cūrā"](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/enn.html), written in [dactylic hexameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dactylic_hexameter).

I added to the text some macrons and caesuras that are of my own. I scrupulously respected what little I knew about Ennius' latin, especially long vowels in active.indicative.present.3S (e.g. in *seruāt*). **Caesuras are largely cosmetic here : please do not take them too seriously.** Feel free to correct me if necessary !

What bothers me is line 96:

> [096]    laeua uolāuit auis. | Simul aureus exorītur sōl
>
> [096]    […] on the left flew a bird. Meanwhile a golden sun appeared […]

I can't scan this line as a regular dactylic hexameter. Everything happens as if *exorītur sōl* should be read *exoritur sōl*. But exorītur comes from *exorīrī*, hence my amazement.

What I'm missing ? Thanks !

---

**update :** There's something interesting about *exoritur*. Virgil has *exoritur* (not *exorītur*), e.g. in Eneid 2.213:

> exoritur clāmorque uirum clangorque tubārum.

The verb seems to hesitate between several stems : see *oreris* in Ovid Metam. 10.166. :

> tū totiēns oreris uiridīqu(e) in caespite flōrēs.

---

```
[080]    Cūrantēs | magnā cum cūrā | tum cupientēs
[081]    regnī | dant operam | simul auspici(ō) auguriōque.
[083]    [-] Remus auspiciō | sē dēuouet | atque secundam
[084]    sōlus auem seruāt. | At Rōmulus pulcher in altō
[085]    quaerit Auentīnō | seruāt genus altiuolantum.
[086]    Certābant urbem | Rōmam Remoramne uocārent.
[087]    Omnibus cūra uirīs | uter essēt induperātor.
[088]    Exspectant uel utī | cōnsul cum mittere signum
[089]    uolt | omnēs auidī | spectant ad carceris ōrās
[090]    quam mox ēmittat | pictīs ē faucibus currus
[091]    sīc exspectābat | populus | atqu(e) ōra tenēbat
[092]    rēbus | utrī magnī | uictōria | sit data regnī.
[093]    intereā | sōl albu(s) recessit | in īnfera noctis.
[094]    Exin candida sē radiīs | dedit īcta forās lux
[095]    et simul ex altō | longē pulcherruma praepes
[096]    laeua uolāuit auis. | Simul aureus exoritur sōl
[097]    Cēdunt dē caelō | ter quattuor corpora sancta
[098]    auium | praepetibus sēsē | pulchrīsque locīs dant.
[099]    Cōnspicit inde sibī | data Rōmulus esse priōra
[100]    auspiciō regnī | stabilīta | scamna solumque.
```

- *auium*(098) is bisyllabic (confer Ernoux, Recueil de textes latins archaïques, p. 150)
- same problem with *quattuor*(097), also bisyllabic (confer Ernoux), some editors read "*quattor*".
- "*albus*" must be read "*albu*" since "[f]inal /s/ [...] was weakly articulated in Old Latin." ("The Blackwell history of the Latin language, p.98")
- *seruāt*(084, 085) : Old Latin (not Latin) had a long here. See e.g. "The Blackwell history of the Latin language, p.98" speaking about the "charateristic Latin shortening of long vowels before [...] /-t/ (3rd person singular)"

Comment: Well, it’s not my insight. I have rearranged the listing order, but I took all information from Ernout’s book, pp. 147-152, which cites Niedermann, *Une loi rythmique proethnique en latin*, Mélanges de Saussure, Paris, Champion, 1908, as the original source.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My source for this answer is A. Ernout, *Morphologie historique du latin,* Paris 1974.

**1. orĭtur/orītur**

Verbs in *-iō* (originated by a well-known indo-european *-ye/o-* suffix attached directly to the verbal root) belong either to the third (ĭ) or the fourth (ī) conjugation, according to a set of rules:

1. Monosyllabic radical, ī: **sciō, scīre.**
2. After a long syllable, ī: **dormiō, dormīre; rūgiō, rūgīre.**
3. After two short syllables, ī: **aperiō, aperīre.**
4. After a sequence of long+short, ĭ: **cōnspiciō, conspicere** (only
   compounds.)
5. After one short syllable followed by a stop, ĭ: **capiō, capere;
   faciō, facere.**
6. After one short syllable followed by *l, n, r, v,* ***mostly*** ī:
   **veniō, venīre**, with several deviations and uncertainties (**morĭor, mori** but archaic **moriri**; **pariō, parere** but archaic **parire**...)
7. Verbs derived from nouns have a tendency to generalise ī, contrary to the above rules: **sĭtiō, sĭtire.**

**Orĭor** belongs to the uncertainties of point 6. In the infinitive, only **oriri** is attested, but forms like **oreris, orĭtur, orĕrētur** are the normal ones. Ennius is archaic, and uses **morīmur** instead of classical **morĭmur,** (Ann. 392), but also **horĭtur** (Ann. 432) and, as you noted, **orĭtur.** So, no problem here.

Developments in Romance languages show that the forms in actual spoken usage must have been more varied than those codified by classical prose.

**2. seruāt**

In classical times, the *a* was shortened and we have *amăt, servăt,* etc., but an *ā* is to be expected from etymology and we do find it in archaic times, in Ennius as in this quotation, but, e.g., also in Plautus: *fundum alienum arāt, incultum familiarem deserit* (Asin. 874, troch. hept.).

Hope this helps.

Comment: "Hope this helps". It does, indeed !

Answer (score 2):

Here are some remarks concerning the marked vowel lengths, caesuras, and scansion.
Many of them are tangential to your actual question, but I hope they are useful.
Most of the caesuras and macrons are correct; I hope my analysis does not come across as too negative for picking mistakes.
First remarks:

- I should stress that my point of view is that of classical Latin, and may not be entirely appropriate for Ennius. I am not as familiar with older Latin.
- Some authors use macrons to denote not only long vowels but also long syllables. I have assumed that you have used them for vowel length only. (I only ever use them so myself, but it is good to be aware of the alternatives.)
- The answer to your actual question seems to be that **the length of *i* in the stem of *oriri* and derivatives can vary, and these verbs seem to be somewhere between conjugations three and four**.
- Caesuras might be just cosmetics for you, but as you have marked them, I find it beneficial for other readers to comment on them.

> [080]    Cūrantēs | magnā cum cūrā | tum cupientēs

Caesuras are typically — I would even say always, but there may be exceptions — placed within a dactyl, not between them.
Therefore the second caesura seems invalid to me.
Caesuras are typically (≈ always) confined to the second, third, and fourth feet of a verse.
The two possible points for a ceasura here are before and after *magna*.
You can consider it to have both caesuras.
I would only put the one after *magna* so as to split the verse more evenly.
(I do not typically put a caesura if there are several options in the same verse, like in 86.)

> [081]    regnī | dant operam | simul auspici(ō) auguriōque.

The same caesura rules from [080] apply:
The two possible positions are right before and after *operam*.

> [084]    sōlus auem seruāt. | At Rōmulus pulcher in altō

The vowel before the third person ending *-t* in *servat*, *audit*, and such is short.
Therefore the macron in *servat* should not be there.
Scansion does require the syllable to be long (heavy) there, though.
This is achieved by a longer pause, and my experience suggests that this is particularly common with punctuation.
(Ennius may not have had punctuation like we do, but a pause for the shift from one sentence or thought to another still makes sense.)

> [085]    quaerit Auentīnō | seruāt genus altiuolantum.

There is a spurious macron in *servat*.

> [089]    uolt | omnēs auidī | spectant ad carceris ōrās

There should be no caesura in the first foot.

> [091]    sīc exspectābat | populus | atqu(e) ōra tenēbat

Here I would only use the second caesura so as to emphasize it.
Namely, the last syllable of *populus* needs to be scanned long, and a sole caesura helps there.

> [092]    rēbus | utrī magnī | uictōria | sit data regnī.

The only two caesura possibilities are before and after *magni*.

> [093]    intereā | sōl albus recessit | in īnfera noctis.

Curiously, the second syllable of *albus* needs to be scanned short here.
Whether this is excessive poetic licence is a matter of taste, but it certainly helps that it is an unstressed syllable for both prose and meter.

> [094]    Exin candida sē radiīs | dēdit īcta forās lux

Scansion requires that the first syllable of *dedit* is short.
And indeed, the vowel is short.
This is not a present form of *dedere* but a perfect form of *dare*.

> [095]    et simul ex altō | longe pulcherruma praepes

There is a macron missing from *longe*.
The meter suggests it, and long *-e* is also standard morphology.

> [096]    laeua uolāuit auis. | Simul aureus exorītur sōl

Indeed, the *i* in *exoritur* has to be scanned short.
I, too, expected it to be long.
At first I thought this is mere poetic licence, but then I checked that [Ovid would use a short *i* as well](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=oritur%23+%5Bov%5D).
The corresponding active form has a short *i* (as is always the case before a word-final *t*), and the *i* is short in *i*-stem verbs of the third conjugation.

My dictionary suggests that *exoriri* is a mixture of third and fourth conjugations, unlike *oriri* which is pure fourth.
Exploring the morphology of prefixed versions of *oriri* would make a nice separate question.
I can only say that the short *i* seems to be correct, but I cannot give the whole paradigm with confidence.

> [098]    auium | praepetibus sēsē | pulchrīsque locīs dant.

The first caesura looks misplaced.
Both sides of *sese* work.

More interestingly, *avium* seems to require a long (heavy) first syllable.
This can be achieved by reading it as *avjum*, with a consonantal *i* and only two syllables.

> [100]    auspiciō regnī | stabilīta | scamna solumque.

The second caesura falls between feet.
A caesura only fits on both sides of *regni*.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answers. I improved my text (see *dedit*(094), *longē*(095) and my remarks about *auium*(098), *quattuor*(097), *albus*(093)). I beg to differ about *seruāt*. See my remarks.

Comment: @sumelic : I beg to differ. I and my colleagues use macrons *only* to mark vowel length : it's the most untrivial information we need to guess syllable length.

Comment: @suizokukan Thanks for the updates! I added some remarks to the start of my answer. I can't tell when the *a* in *servat* shortened or if it was ever long in the first place; older Latin is not my strongest suit. I hope this answer is of use anyway.

Comment: yes, thank you very much for everything you noticed in my post, it was helpfull !